# Fill missing values in a matrix with values from different rows in that matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix with nucleotide sequences (containing NAs) in rows as shown here:

**n.mat**

```
samp1 <- c("a","c","a",NA,"t","c")
samp2 <- c("a","c","t","t",NA,"a")
samp3 <- c("a","g","g","c","a","c")
samp4 <- c("a","g",NA,"g","g", NA)
samp5<- c(NA, "g","g","g","t","g")

n.mat <- rbind(samp1,samp2,samp3,samp4,samp5)

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
samp1 "a"  "c"  "a"   NA  "t"  "c" 
samp2 "a"  "c"  "t"  "t"   NA  "a" 
samp3 "a"  "g"  "g"  "c"  "a"  "a" 
samp4 "a"  "g"   NA  "g"  "g"   NA 
samp5  NA  "g"  "g"  "g"  "t"  "g"
```

I also have a data frame with two columns containing the sequence names:

**df**

```
df <- data.frame(
  X1 = c("samp1", "samp2", "samp3", "samp4", "samp5"),
  X2 = c("samp2", "samp5", "samp1", "samp3", "samp2"))

          X1       X2
1      samp1    samp2
2      samp2    samp5
3      samp3    samp1
4      samp4    samp3
5      samp5    samp2
```

I would like to fill the gaps of a row in the matrix with nucleotides/values from another row in the matrix indicated by the `df$X2` column in the data frame.

So for example: `samp1` in the matrix has an `NA` in its row in the fourth column. So I would like to take the string in the same column from `samp2` (indicated by the data frame in column `X2`). For `samp2` I would like to fill the `NA` by taking the string from `samp5` (indicated by the data frame in column `X2`).
If there is no `NA` in the row as it is in `samp3`, then do nothing.
If there are two `NAs` in a row (as it is in `samp4`), then I would like to take both strings from `samp3` both columns.

I have tried following code:

```
replace.na <- function(n.mat,val) {
  i <- is.na(n.mat)
  j <- which(i)
  k <- which(!i)
  n.mat[j[j > k[length(k)]]] <- val
  n.mat
}

n.mat[,-1] <- t(apply(matrix[,-1],1,replace.na))
```

But I am not quite sure how to include the `df` table to replace the `NAs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some very compact code that I will explain (and it assumes either using R v 4.x or creating the 'df' dataframe with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`):

```
n.mat[ is.na(n.mat) ] <-  n.mat[df[['X2']],][ is.na(n.mat)]

n.mat
#------
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
samp1 "a"  "c"  "a"  "t"  "t"  "c" 
samp2 "a"  "c"  "t"  "t"  "t"  "a" 
samp3 "a"  "g"  "g"  "c"  "a"  "a" 
samp4 "a"  "g"  "g"  "g"  "g"  "a" 
samp5 "a"  "g"  "g"  "g"  "t"  "g"
```

The `is.na(.n.mat)` returns a logical matrix of the same dimension as n.mat. It is used as an index on both sides of the assignment but on the right side of the assignment is is picking from a matrix that has the rows rearranged by the ordering of the "replacement rows" that you specified in `df`. If the 'X1' column had not been ibn the same order as the target matrix, you would have needed to reorder that column via an `order` call, but it wasn't needed here.

```
 df <- read.table(text= 'X1       X2
 1      samp1    samp2
 2      samp2    samp5
 3      samp3    samp1
 4      samp4    samp3
 5      samp5    samp2', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Note the `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`. I think my failing to use that (since I'm still on R 3.6 meant that I had factors in the X2 column.

The other way of doing this is to create a two column index of NA positions with the arr.idx parameter set to TRUE:

```
 pos <- which(is.na(n.mat),arr.ind=TRUE)

> pos
      row col
samp5   5   1
samp4   4   3
samp1   1   4
samp2   2   5
samp4   4   6
```

Then you can index with that 2 column matrix:

```
 n.mat[pos] <- n.mat[ df[['X2']] ,][pos]

> n.mat
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
samp1 "a"  "c"  "a"  "t"  "t"  "c" 
samp2 "a"  "c"  "t"  "t"  "t"  "a" 
samp3 "a"  "g"  "g"  "c"  "a"  "a" 
samp4 "a"  "g"  "g"  "g"  "g"  "a" 
samp5 "a"  "g"  "g"  "g"  "t"  "g"
```

R's matrix indexing can produce some very compact solutions to problems like this. You should consider reading the `?'['` help page for more details and examples. The time you put into that effort will be repaid many times over if you continue using R. I'm sure I've read through it 10 or 20 times by now.

Reprex:

```
n.mat <- matrix( scan(text = 'samp1 "a"  "c"  "a"  "NA" "t"  "c" 
 samp2 "a"  "c"  "t"  "t"  "NA" "a" 
 samp3 "a"  "g"  "g"  "c"  "a"  "a" 
 samp4 "a"  "g"  "NA" "g"  "g"  "NA" 
 samp5 "NA" "g"  "g"  "g"  "t"  "g" ', what=""), nrow=5, byrow=TRUE)

 n.mat <- matrix(n.mat[ ,-1], nrow=5, dimnames=list(n.mat[,1], NULL))

df <- read.table(text= 'X1       X2
 1      samp1    samp2
 2      samp2    samp5
 3      samp3    samp1
 4      samp4    samp3
 5      samp5    samp2', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, I think your idea was very helpful and it works quite nice if there are no repetitions. But I think the `NA` from the second row and 5th column of the matrix wasn't converted correctly. It should be a `t`. I was also checking with different arrangements of the `NAs` and then it won't convert every `NA`. Do you maybe have another option?

Comment: The code was correct (I think) but I suspect both of us were using R 3.6 or below and accepting the default of `stringsAsFactors` for data.frame creation. There should not be a problem with multiple NAs in a line. There might be a problem if there were no entry for a particualr row of the n.mat matrix in the df replacement table. In that case you should put in a place holder with a row referencing itself.  eg `3 sampx sampx`

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this below. Note that the output is a bit different, but I copied/pasted your code for creating your matrix (see `samp3` column 6).

```
t(sapply(rownames(n.mat), function(x) {
  na_cols <- is.na(n.mat[x, ])
  n.mat[x, na_cols] <- n.mat[df[df$X1 == x, "X2"], na_cols]
  n.mat[x, ]
}))
```

**Output**

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
samp1 "a"  "c"  "a"  "t"  "t"  "c" 
samp2 "a"  "c"  "t"  "t"  "t"  "a" 
samp3 "a"  "g"  "g"  "c"  "a"  "c" 
samp4 "a"  "g"  "g"  "g"  "g"  "c" 
samp5 "a"  "g"  "g"  "g"  "t"  "g"
```

**Data**

```
n.mat <- structure(c("a", "a", "a", "a", NA, "c", "c", "g", "g", "g", 
"a", "t", "g", NA, "g", NA, "t", "c", "g", "g", "t", NA, "a", 
"g", "t", "c", "a", "c", NA, "g"), .Dim = 5:6, .Dimnames = list(
    c("samp1", "samp2", "samp3", "samp4", "samp5"), NULL))
```

Comment: Check your result and check to see if your df$X2 is a factor.

Comment: My `df$X2` was not a factor, just a character vector (I'm using R 4.0.2 and may be getting used to `stringsAsFactors` as `FALSE` for default)...BTW, I like your compact code/answer...

Comment: I'm getting different results. Look at column 6, rows 3 and 4.

Comment: Hmm...I got the same results as your answer. I wonder if this may be due to a difference in `n.mat` data. The OP example data may have changed - `samp3` vector ends with "c" - but after `rbind` the `n.mat` matrix has row `samp3` col 6 as "a". I'll add my example data to my answer (though tempted to remove, not sure how useful it is).

Comment: You're right. The OP changed the example and didn't tell us. I was using the original problem.